# Sign of exponential in Fourier Coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

So I have usually seen Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)$ of a $2\pi$ periodic function $f$ defined as:

$$\hat{f}(n) = 
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \exp (inx) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)
$$
So $f$ has series representation:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n)\exp(-inx)
$$

Now, my question is: what difference does the change in signs make? I know the point is to leverage the identity:

$$
\langle\exp(-inx) , \exp(ikx) \rangle_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)} =
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp(-inx)\exp(ikx)\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \delta_{n,k}
$$
But do we need the difference in signs? I thought the that the $\exp(inx)$ already form an orthonormal basis of $L^2$, so the above identity should follow without the need for different signs. Also, I had one more question,  (albeit basic) but something I still need clarification on. Does the fourier series of every $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ function converge to the function in norm? I.e, does:
$$
\left \|\sum_{|n|<N} \hat{f}(n)\exp(-inx) -f\right \|_{L^2} \to 0 \quad \text{as } N \to \infty$$

Comment: Your scalar product is wrong. Fourier series don't always converge in $L^2$. Difference in signs doesn't make any difference in terms of the series itself

Comment: are ypu referring to the missing factor of $2\pi$?

Comment: To the factor of $2\pi$ and to missing complex conjugate

Comment: Where should the conjugate go? I (think) I am assuming the inner product is real valued.

Comment: $\langle f, g \rangle = \int f\, \overline{g} $

Comment: That fixes it. Thank you.